# Is there a way to use Family Link group in my own application?

Tags: mobile, client-server

Although I am experienced developer, I am very new to mobile app. I am wondering if it is possible to create application which will communicate between devices from Family Link group.

In principle my requirement is to create application integrated between mine and kids devices. However I would like to avoid classic server-client integration (I don't want to build a server for this purpose).

I know it is quite generic question, but maybe someone can point me out where I can start. I did some quick research, but did not find any close hits.

BTW - I want to use Visual Studio and Xamarin for this purpose.